# Remove item in Masonry “Remove Method” by clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-masonry, masonry

**Overview:**

I am using Masonry Cascading grid layout library and adding Masonry Remove Method.
This method allows to click on **any part** of the item --> remove it--> and rests nicely the layout.

**Issue:**

I would like to remove an item (`<div class="item 1"></div>` “pink-box”) **only** by clicking on a specific area (i.e. button) within the item.

I tried to manipulate the function within the JavaScript file, but was unsuccessful to find a solution to my problem. (I started for the first time to build some website 2month ago, so have very little experience in jS or jQ)

**Question:**

Do you have any rough idea how I could fix this issue?

Here is a link to jsfiddle to show a brief overview of what I would like to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/intimur/SfU5T/22/

**HTML**

```
<div class="masonry">
 <div class="item 1"></div>  
 <div class="item 2">      
     <div class="remove-btn"> Click here to remove item </div>      
 </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
// http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js added as external resource
// added http://rawgithub.com/desandro/classie/master/classie.js

docReady( function() {

  var container = document.querySelector('.masonry');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    columnWidth: 200
  });

  eventie.bind( container, 'click', function( event ) {
    // don't proceed if item was not clicked on
    if ( !classie.has( event.target, 'item' ) ) {
      return;
    }
    // remove clicked element
    msnry.remove( event.target );
    // layout remaining item elements
    msnry.layout();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't checked yet the classie.js as I don't know if it's really needed to remove the item by clicking the button. Just adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SfU5T/28/) with:

```
$(document).on('click', ".remove-btn", function () {
    msnry.remove($(this).parent(".item"));
    msnry.layout();
});
```

If you already have the .remove-btn in the actual DOM, it's not necessary to delegate the click-event to the .remove-button from the $(document), so if this is the case this can be simplified to

```
 $(".remove-btn").click(function () {
    msnry.remove($(this).parent(".item"));
    msnry.layout();
});
```

Adjusted [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SfU5T/29/) for this version.